# Compound Key Performance For App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am creating string datastore IDs for entity "A" from auto-generated IDs of entity "B." Should I prefix the A ID with "A-PREFIX"-B.IntID() or go with B.IntID()+"A-PREFIX?"

I assume I should start with the B ID because they are uniformly distributed so as to prevent hotspots?

From https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore

Anti-Pattern #1: Sequential Numbering of Entity Keys

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need any prefix at all. A key consists of an entity kind and an ID. So two entities may have the same ID and still have unique keys if they belong to different kinds.

This example works perfectly fine (example in Java):

```
Entity userEntity = new Entity("User");
Long id = datastore.put(userEntity).getId();

Entity loginEntity = new Entity("Login", id);
datastore.put(loginEntity);
```

Note that if you take a Long id and convert it into a String, your keys will take up much more space. So using a Long for an id is a better option.

Comment: Good point! Although if I also had a C, which had the same kind as A, and I wanted to relate C to B, then I would need to use string prefix, right?

Comment: No, you can simply reference B in a C entity as a property (`userEntity.setProperty("users_relative", otherUserEntity.getKey().getId())`), or make C a child entity of B. I cannot think of any use case where a prefix is necessary.

Comment: You're right I could simply store the B Key in C or vice-versa depending on how I need to go. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: It's better to store an ID - you can always create a key from an id. An id will take much less space than a full key.